# Django field error messages

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have fields in a django form that require an integer.
the default value in the field is '-'.
This means that when a user ignores the field, an form field error is returned.
Annoyingly the message has an annoying 'u' in it.

How do I get rid of the U?

the html

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
   {% with childForm.age as field %}
      <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}" id="children-age">
          {{ field }}
          {% if field.errors %}<p class="help-block">{% for error in field.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}</p>{% endif %}
       </div>
    {% endwith %}
 </div>
```

the error

[image: screenshot of the error]

forms.py

```
class TravelGeneralEnquiryForm(forms.ModelForm):
children = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('','-'),) + tuple(((str(x), x) for x in range(0, 11))), required=True)
adults = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('','-'),) + tuple(((str(x), x) for x in range(1, 11))), required=True)
pets = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((str(x), x) for x in range(0, 11)), required=True, initial=1)
budget = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BUDGET,required=False)
interest_destination = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
                                            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                            choices=INTEREST_DESTINATION_CHOICES)
interest_accommodation = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
                                            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                            choices=INTEREST_ACCOMMODATION_CHOICES)
contact_preference = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                                            widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                            choices=CONTACT_PREFERENCE)
inspire_hours = forms.ChoiceField(choices=INSPIRE_HOURS, required=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TravelGeneralEnquiryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name_title'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control',}
    self.fields['name_title'].label = 'Title*'
    self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control',}
    self.fields['first_name'].label = 'First name*'
    self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control',}
    self.fields['last_name'].label = 'Last name*'
    self.fields['email'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control',}
    self.fields['email'].label = 'Email address*'
    self.fields['telephone'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control',}
    self.fields['telephone'].label = 'Telephone number*'
    self.fields['check_in_date'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control datepicker', 'data-date-format': 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'autocomplete': 'off',}
    self.fields['check_in_date'].widget.format = '%d/%m/%Y'
    self.fields['check_in_date'].input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y']
    self.fields['check_in_date'].label = 'Check in date*'
    self.fields['check_out_date'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control datepicker', 'data-date-format': 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'autocomplete': 'off',}
    self.fields['check_out_date'].widget.format = '%d/%m/%Y'
    self.fields['check_out_date'].input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y']
    self.fields['check_out_date'].label = 'Check out date*'
    self.fields['budget'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}
    self.fields['info'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '3', 'placeholder': 'Pet breed/size/temperament/food allergies/disabled access'}
    self.fields['adults'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}
    self.fields['adults'].label = 'Number of adults*'
    self.fields['children'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'initial': '---'}
    self.fields['children'].label = 'Number of children*'
    self.fields['pets'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}
    self.fields['pets'].label = 'Number of pets*'
    self.fields['rooms'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}
    self.fields['rooms'].label = 'Number of rooms*'
    self.fields['contact_preference'].label = 'Prefered method of contact'
    self.fields['inspire_postcode'].label = 'Your Postcode'
    self.fields['inspire_postcode'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'N1 4SZ'}
    self.fields['inspire_hours'].label = 'How far would you like to travel?'
    self.fields['inspire_hours'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}
    self.fields['inspire_details'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '2', 'cols':50 , 'placeholder': 'The more information you give us, the better we are able to help you!'}
    self.fields['inspire_details'].label = 'Additional Information'


class Meta:
    model =  TravelGeneralEnquiry
    exclude = ('enquiry_source',)

class TravelGeneralEnquiryChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    age = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('-','-'),) + tuple(((str(x), x) for x in range(0, 18))))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TravelGeneralEnquiryChildForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['age'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}

class Meta:
    model =  TravelGeneralEnquiryChild
    fields = ('age',)


class TravelGeneralEnquiryChild(models.Model):
    general_enquiry = models.ForeignKey(TravelGeneralEnquiry, blank=False, null=False, related_name="general_enquiry_children")
    age = models.CharField(max_length=2, default=0, null=False, blank=False, choices=((str(x), x) for x in range(0, 18)))
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the `u` isn't random, it is representing a unicode string type.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that. cheers though..

Comment: How are you constructing the error message? The default error message for me in Django 1.8 is `Select a valid choice. - is not one of the available choices.'`, which does not have the `u''` prefix.

Comment: unfortunately I'm using Django 1.5

Comment: I get the same error message in Django 1.5 as 1.8, What do your form and view look like - it looks like you have some custom code running that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Ok, now that you have added more code, I can see that the error message is coming from the [model validation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ee66d8dd7df8326c453fd04c2bdeb5225df934be/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L110), not the form validation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the error message has the `u''` prefix. I suggest you change the *value* of the choice to the empty string `''`.

```
class TravelGeneralEnquiryChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    age = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('','-'),) + tuple(((str(x), x) for x in range(0, 18))))
```

That way you'll get the error message `This field is required.` instead of the invalid choice error message.